# How do I pass values between React Redux components?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have tried and failed to understand react/redux and have inherited some code (very simplified version shared here). There is a navigator:

```
class processNavigator extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  render() {
    switch (this.props.processStatus) {
      case processStatus.ended:
        return <Page2 />;
      case processStatus.notStarted:
        return <Page1 myToken={this.myToken} />;
```

which renders either page1 or page2.

Page1:

```
interface StateProps {
  processId: number | undefined;
  processStatus: processStatus | undefined;
}
interface DispatchProps {
  startprocess: () => void;
}
type Page1Props = RouteComponentProps &
  DispatchProps &
  NavigatorProps &
  StateProps;

class Page1 extends React.Component<Page1Props, {state variables
}> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { state variables
    };
  }
   startTypeGetPromise = async (myToken: string): Promise<any> => {
    DB lookup here
    return aValue; 
  };
  loadResult = async () => {
    await this.startTypeGetPromise(this.props.myToken).then(ret => this.setState({startTypeValue: ret}));
  };

  componentDidMount () {this.loadResult();};
  render() {return (...);}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState): StateProps => ({
  processId: state.process.processId,
  processStatus: state.process.processStatus,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch): DispatchProps => ({
  startprocess: () => dispatch(startprocess()),
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(withRouter(withTranslation()(Page1)));
```

Page2:

```
interface StateProps {
  processId: number | undefined;
  processStatus: processStatus;
}

type Page2Props = RouteComponentProps & StateProps;

class Page2 extends React.Component<Page2Props> {
  render() {...);}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState): StateProps => ({
  processId: state.process.processId,
  processStatus: state.process.processStatus,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(
  withRouter(withTranslation()(processPage2))
);
```

How do I pass the state value `startTypeValue` from `Page1` to `Page2`? (Apologies for all the code, I am not sure what is boiler plate and what is needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move startTypeValue to the upper component's state and pass it as a prop to Page2. For changing startTypeValue from Page1 component one can pass a callback function-prop:

```
class processNavigator extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    startTypeValue: null // or some other initial value you want
  }

  render() {
    switch (this.props.processStatus) {
      case processStatus.ended:
        return <Page2 startTypeValue={this.state.startTypeValue} />;
      case processStatus.notStarted:
        return <Page1
                 myToken={this.myToken}
                 onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({ startTypeValue: value })}
                />;
  }
}
```

In Page1 component:

```
loadResult = async () => {
  await this.startTypeGetPromise(this.props.myToken)
    .then(ret => this.props.onValueChange(ret));
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, finally got round to trying this...If I make that change to `Page1` how can I access the value of `startTypeValue` in `Page1` since it is used in both pages?

Comment: @schoon from the code you provided it seems that you don't need the *startTypeValue* in *Page1* state, just use the *onValueChange* callback. If you really need the *startTypeValue* in the *Page1* component for some reason, you can pass it as a prop just like it's already done in *Page2* component.